# C - Errors in header file

Tags: arrays

i'm getting the following errors associated with my header file for some functions and I am not sure how to resolve them:

```
prog8.c: In function 'main':
prog8.c:17: error: expected expression before ']' token
prog8.c:20: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
prog8.c:21: error: expected expression before ']' token
prog8.c:25: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
prog8.c:26: error: expected expression before ']' token
prog8.c:29: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
prog8.c:30: error: expected expression before ']' token
```

Here is the header file code:

```
#ifndef ARRAYFUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define ARRAYFUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED

int arraySmallest(int [], int );

int arrayLargest(int [], int );

int arraySum(int [], int );

int arrayAverage(int [], int);

#endif
```

C File:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ArrayFunctions.h"

/* Smallest */

int arraySmallest(int array[], int size)
{
int i, min = array[0];
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if (array[i] < min)
    {
        min = array[i];
    }
}
return min;
}

/* Largest */

int arrayLargest(int array[], int size)
{
int i, max = array[0];
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if (array[i] > max)
    {
        max = array[i];
    }
}
return max;
}

/* Sum */

int arraySum(int array[], int size)
{
int i, sum = array[0];
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    sum += array[i];
}
return sum;
}

/* Sum */

int arrayAverage(int array[], int size)
{
int i, avg = array[0], sum = array[0];
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    sum += array[i];
}
avg = sum / size
return avg;
}
```

Here is the driver:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ArrayFunctions.h"

int main()
{

/* smallest */
int array[5] = {2, 8, 3, 4, 5};
printf("%d/n", (arraySmallest(array[], 5)));

/* largest */
int array2[5] = {2, 8, 3, 4, 5};
printf("%d/n", (arrayLargest(array2[], 5)));


/* sum */
int array3[5] = {2, 8, 3, 4, 5};
printf("%d/n", (arraySum(array3[], 5)));

/* average */
int array4[5] = {2, 8, 3, 4, 5};
printf("%d/n", (arrayAverage(array4[], 5)));

return 0;
}
```

Thanks so much for any help in advance!

Comment: The error is in the caller. Post the code where you call these functions.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I added that in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters require you pass an array, but you only pass an integer:

```
int array[5] = {2, 8, 3, 4, 5}; 
printf("%d/n", (arraySmallest(array[5], 5)));
// ---------------------------------^
```

You do this with all the calls. Simply remove `[5]`.

Comment: Thank you, I've made this change and most errors are gone, the few that remain I'll add to the original post

Comment: @user28374 Remove the 5 AND the brackets.

Comment: Ahhh ok that fixes it. Thank you so much for pointing these errors out and helping me!

Answer (score 3):

Your function defs in your C file have semicolons at the end of the def line.

e.g.:

```
8: int arrayLargest(int array[], int size);
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed several issues